# How to prevent authenticated user from spoofing restful api calls

Tags: rest

So I build a RESTful API. It has an `/account/{id}` endpoint to return user data. The API is secured via an identity server that issues the requester a JSON Web token (JWT) with access to the `/account/{id}` endpoint. The user sends a request with username and password and receives a JWT in return on successful authentication. Now the user sends a request for their account information to `/account/{id}`. The request is sent with a token in the header and returns a 200 response with the user data in the payload.

How would one go about authorizing the {id} in the endpoint? In other words, an authenticated user could just add any {id} in the endpoint and potentially receive another user's data. How is this prevented using the JWT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store data in a web token. If you store the ID of the user, then you can identify them for each request they make. This is safe, because the contents of the token are signed with the private key of the server. Therefore their contents cannot be changed.

After that you can either limit the API so that each user can only query their own record, or you can also implement a complex role system, where each user has a set of roles (e.g. `read-only`, `guest`, `maintainer`, `admin`, `client`, etc.) that define which endpoints and how they can use.

Comment: So to limit the API so that each user can only query their own record, do I just check that the logged in user Id equals the {id} in uri?

Comment: Yes. But you can store in the database additional information about the user permissions. For example an `is_admin` field in the user record. If they have it set to true, then they could read any record. About storing the ID: the user ID should be known when creating the token, because that happens after a successful authentication.

Comment: Or you could go for another path e.g. /me